# Is there a way to have an association has_many through with join table not obligatory in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, associations, has-many-through, model-associations

I want an idea how to make the associations of the models to accomplish a task in Ruby on Rails. I have 3 tables. User, spread and group. Group can have many users, user can belong only to one group. Group of users can have their own spreads but also a specific user can have his own spreads (without being part of a group). How can I create spreads for the user without creating a group in this case?

For the moment I have these relations:

User:

```
has_many :spreads, through :group
```

Group:

```
has_many :users
has many :spreads
```

Spread:

```
belong_to :group
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Polymorphic Association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). So your associations would be something like:

User:

```
has_many :spreads, as: :parent
```

Group:

```
has_many :users
has many :spreads, as: :parent
```

Spread:

```
belong_to :parent, polymorphic: true
```